# Problems using org.apache.lucene on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, lucene, guice, google-cloud-endpoints

Hi on my last project I used the lucene-analyzer for generating keywords on appengine. Now i want to use it again with my new project but it seems that it is restricted by GAE. I tried to set the version back to the version I used at my last Project but it doesn´t work anymore. I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.<clinit>(RamUsageEstimator.java:223)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.util.ArrayUtil.<clinit>(ArrayUtil.java:32)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttributeImpl.<init>(CharTermAttributeImpl.java:33)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PackedTokenAttributeImpl.<init>(PackedTokenAttributeImpl.java:40)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeFactory$1.createInstance(AttributeFactory.java:140)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeFactory$StaticImplementationAttributeFactory.createAttributeInstance(AttributeFactory.java:103)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource.addAttribute(AttributeSource.java:222)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.<init>(StandardTokenizer.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.analysis.de.GermanAnalyzer.createComponents(GermanAnalyzer.java:194)
[INFO]  at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:144)
```

does anybody know why i get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because Lucene's `RamUsageEstimator` tries to access the `ManagementFactory` class to determine the VM's object alignment. `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` is restricted on GAE (probably for security reasons), and a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.

If you look at [LuceneAppEngine](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine) and [LuGAEne](https://github.com/svenjacobs/lugaene) (projects providing a directory implementation that lets you use Lucene on Google App Engine), you can see that they provide an alternative `RamUsageEstimator`, where they catch that exception:

- https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine/blob/416f86f1ab303d37d183af9e7e220b22437d71b9/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/util/RamUsageEstimator.java#L179
- https://github.com/svenjacobs/lugaene/blob/a3ced4f2a112d3810c4c5a0d84d4efcf4bf1e709/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/util/RamUsageEstimator.java#L250

I think you should consider using one of these "lucene-GAE" projects if you want to use the lucene-analyzer on GAE.

I don't know why it worked for you in your previous project. Maybe you used one of these lucene-GAE projects and forgot to include it in the new project?